# What is Forms Authentication's, OnAuthenticate Event?

Tags: asp.net, events, membership, global-asax

I'm using Asp.net Membership provider. I want to know which event triggered when a person authenticated on site. ( I mean login)

my authentication mode is forms

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

I tried

```
FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate
```

this event at global.asax. But it is triggering not only login, it triggers all requests.

I think Asp.net must have this event. So which is??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question in such a way that you want to get one event each time the user logs in, but only once per session. Since you are using Membership provider I guess you also use the login control.

In that case it seems to me that are looking for the `LogggedIn`, not in the global.asax but as an event of the Login control.

Occurs when the user logs in to the Web site and has been authenticated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply, I solved my problem with this event. But I can't remember, why I want global.asax event :)